# How to restrict random (unidentified) requests to a DRF based API hosted on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework

I'm running a DRF based API deployed with Docker on an EC2 Instance. After a few days of deploying I started facing an issue where the API stopped responding properly and that's when I noticed unidentified requests to my application, and that too at huge volumes. An example screenshot is attached below:

[image: EC2 Nginx Logs]

Although all these requests ultimately return 503 because these pages do not essentially exist, I want to take steps to restrict such requests.

FYR, I have a frontend (React JS Based) app running on AWS Amplify which consumes this API. I was looking for ways to restrict inbound requests to this EC2 to only the Amplify app, but realised that Amplify doesn't offer a Static IP of it's own. Any solution to that would also be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have also put my domain name in the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in my DRF, I am still receiving such hits.

Comment: I think to achieve what you want you can use some throttling libraries. But it would only works for specific view like login. I just guess, but if you deploy you infra with ALB, maybe you can set some rate-limiter or something like that in ALB?

Comment: @KubaRonkiewicz I'm not sure how that would help me prevent my API from unauthorised usage